# Spring Boot Actuator - Custom Endpoints

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am using `Spring Boot Actuator` module in my project which exposes REST endpoint URLs to monitor & manage application usages in production environment, without coding & configuration for any of them.

By default, only `/health` and `/info` endpoints are exposed.

I am customising the endpoints via `application.properties` file as per my use case.

```
application.properties.

#To expose all endpoints
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
 
#To expose only selected endpoints
management.endpoints.jmx.exposure.include=health,info,env,beans
```

I want to understand, where exactly does Spring Boot create actual endpoints for `/health` and `/info` and how does it expose them over HTTP?

Comment: Also have a look at the Javadoc of Endpoint and the related/ linked classes: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/annotation/Endpoint.html

Comment: Its not clear what are you trying to solve. Do you want to see the source code of spring-boot-actuator? Its available here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator, check it out and see in the IDE who uses `@Endpoint` Annotation. You'll see EndpointRequestMatcher that in turn is called by the actuator engine, but I doubt that this information is enough to resolve the issue you face (whatever it is :) )

Comment: Thanks Puce and Mark Bramnik for pointing me into the right direction. Appreciate the guidance! I have added an answer as a solution to my problem, in case folks need something similar in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks @Puce and @MarkBramnik for helping me out with the reference docs & code repository.

I wanted to understand how the endpoints were working and how they were exposed over HTTP, so that I could create custom endpoints to leverage in my application.

*One of the great features of Spring Framework is that it’s very easy to extend, and I was able to achieve the same.*

To create a custom actuator endpoints, Use @Endpoint annotation on a class. Then leverage `@ReadOperation` / `@WriteOperation` / `@DeleteOperation` annotations on the methods to expose them as actuator endpoint bean as needed.

Reference Doc : [Implementing Custom Endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-endpoints-custom)

**Reference Example :**

```
@Endpoint(id="custom_endpoint")
@Component
public class MyCustomEndpoint {

    @ReadOperation
    @Bean
    public String greet() {
        return "Hello from custom endpoint";
    }
}
```

The endpoint id i.e custom_endpoint needs to be configured in the list of actuator endpoints to be enabled.

`application.properties` :

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info,custom_endpoint
```

After a restart, endpoint works like a charm!

Comment: why did you use @Bean for method greet()?